# How to remove/add spaces in all textfiles?

Tags: unix, sed, whitespace

I have several files that look like these, e.g. `test.in`:

```
apple foo bar
hello world
```

I need to achieve this desired output, a space after every character:

```
a p p l e f o o b a r
h e l l o w o r l d
```

I though possibly i'll first remove all spaces and then add spaces to each character, as such:

```
sed 's/\s//g' test.in | sed -e 's/\(.\)/\1 /g'
```

but is there other ways?

Comment: so you want space after last character.

Comment: after every acharacter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can combine your two `sed` commands into a single command instead:

```
$ sed 's/\s//g;s/./& /g' test.in 
a p p l e f o o b a r 
h e l l o w o r l d
```

Note the use of `.` and `&` instead of `\(.\)` and `\1`.

On systems that do not support `\s` to designate matching whitespace, you can use `[[::blank::]]` instead:

```
$ sed 's/[[:blank:]]//g;s/./& /g' test.in 
a p p l e f o o b a r 
h e l l o w o r l d
```

Comment: This is more or less the same as user2196728 posted.

Comment: @Jotne: Same time, but, I was specifically combining the OP's original command.

Comment: See that now. Deleted my comment.

Comment: Note that not all versions of `sed` support `\s` to mean 'space'.  Consider the verbose but flexible `[[:space:]]` or `[[:blank:]]` character classes instead.

Answer (score 3):

This `awk` may do:

```
awk -v FS="" '{gsub(/ /,"");$1=$1}1' file
a p p l e f o o b a r
h e l l o w o r l d
```

This first remove all space, then since `FS` (Field Separator) is set to nothing, the `$1=$1` reconstruct all fields with one space.

This does not add space at the end as most of the other `sed` and `perl` command here.

---

Or based on `sed` posted here.

```
awk '{gsub(/ /,"");gsub(/./,"& ")}1' file
a p p l e f o o b a r
h e l l o w o r l d
```

Comment: there's double spaces in this output.

Comment: @alvas removed extra space.

Answer (score 2):

Through perl,

```
$ perl -ple 's/([^ ]|^)(?! )/\1 /g' file
a p p l e f o o b a r 
h e l l o w o r l d
```

Add an inline edit option `-i` to save the changes made,

```
perl -i -ple 's/([^ ]|^)(?! )/\1 /g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

`sed 's/ //g;s/./& /g' filename`

`&`: refers to that portion of the pattern space which matched

Answer (score 2):

Or maybe something like this with `sed` :

```
$ sed 's/./& /g;s/  //g' file
a p p l e f o o b a r
h e l l o w o r l d
```

Comment: Or this `sed 's/ //g;s/./& /g'`

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you (GNU  sed):

```
sed 's/\B/ /g' file
```