# Locale error when adding a space after each character for a unicode file?

Tags: bash, unicode, utf-8, sed, locale

I want to add spaces to each character in a textfile

**in.txt**

```
在吗？？
嗯
你让我看的那款手提是不是11寸的，很小的？
看来还是美国的便宜啊
应该是吧
```

**out.txt**

```
在 吗 ？ ？
嗯
你 让 我 看 的 那 款 手 提 是 不 是 1 1 寸 的 ， 很 小 的 ？
看 来 还 是 美 国 的 便 宜 啊
应 该 是 吧
```

I've tried this ([How to remove/add spaces in all textfiles?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464590/how-to-remove-add-spaces-in-all-textfiles)) but it outputs:

```
� � � � � � � � � � � � 
� � � 
� � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � 1 1 � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � 
� � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � 
� � � � � � � � � � � �
```

**How do I achieve `out.txt`?**

---

I've also tried:

```
$ perl -F'' -C -lane 'print join " ", @F' in.txt 
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_PAPER = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_ADDRESS = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MONETARY = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NUMERIC = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_TELEPHONE = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_IDENTIFICATION = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_MEASUREMENT = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_TIME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LC_NAME = "de_DE.UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_US.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
� � � � � � � � � � � �
� � �
� � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � 1 1 � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
� � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � � �
� � � � � � � � � � � �
```

And

```
$ cat in.txt 在吗？？
嗯
你让我看的那款手提是不是11寸的，很小的？
看来还是美国的便宜啊
应该是吧
$ sed 's/\s/g;s/./& /g'  in.txt
sed: -e expression #1, char 10: unknown option to `s'
```

The seem to be something wrong with my locale:

```
$ locale
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TIME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_NAME=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ADDRESS=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=de_DE.UTF-8
LC_ALL=
```

To fix it, i had to do:

```
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8
export LANGUAGE=en_US.UTF-8
```

And then:

```
$ perl -F'' -C -lane 'print join " ", @F' in.txt 
在 吗 ？ ？
嗯
你 让 我 看 的 那 款 手 提 是 不 是 1 1 寸 的 ， 很 小 的 ？
看 来 还 是 美
```

Comment: `sed 's/./& /g'` works here. what's your `$LANG`? also what's output of `file in.txt`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have a UTF-8 locale set up correctly, you can use this Perl one-liner:

```
perl -F'' -C -lane 'print join " ", @F' in.txt > out.txt
```

The `-a` switch splits the input on the field separator, which has been set to an empty string, so each character is a separate element in the array `@F`. Since this uses `join`, there is no space added after the last character on the line (it's not clear whether there should be one or not).

Another option is to use a substitution:

```
perl -C -pe 's/(.)/$1 /g' in.txt > out.txt
```

This will add a space after every character, including the last one.

Comment: the perl script works but the locale is was causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Check if UTF-8 is set properly,

```
env | grep -i utf
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

You can refer following link for knowing more about language settings.

http://perlgeek.de/en/article/set-up-a-clean-utf8-environment

The following oneliner works fine.

```
 sed 's/\s/g;s/./& /g'  in.txt
```

Here is the sample output:

```
sed 's/\s//g;s/./& /g'  in.txt 
在 吗 ？ ？ 
嗯 
你 让 我 看 的 那 款 手 提 是 不 是 1 1 寸 的 ， 很 小 的 ？ 
看 来 还 是 美 国 的 便 宜 啊 
应 该 是 吧
```

Comment: The perlgeek link fixed the locale but the sed is not working.